# collision detection between two lines

Tags: math, geometry, collision-detection

This is a fairly simple question. I need need an equation to determine whether two 2 dimensional lines collide with each other. If they do I also need to know the X and Y position of the collision.

Comment: Are you asking how to check if two lines intersect, or if the paths of two moving lines ever caused the lines to intersect?

Comment: A tip which I really want to give you is: if you ever have a geometry question, first check: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/. Paul Bourke wrote a lot of these common issues, such as yours: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/.

Answer (score 2):

Put them both in [general form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#General_form). If A and B are the same then they're parallel. Otherwise, create two simultaneous equations and solve for x and y.

Comment: @aioobe: General form does not suffer from the same problem as slope-intercept form.

Answer (score 0):

Let **A** and **B** represented by this parametric form : **y = mx + b**
Where **m** is the *slope* of the line
Now in the case of parallelism of **A** and **B** their *slope* should be equal

Else they will collide with each other at point **T(x,y)**
For finding the coordinates of point **T** you have to solve an easy equation:

**A: y = mx + b**
**B: y = Mx + B**
**y(A) = y(B)** means : **mx + b = Mx + B** which yields to **x = (B - b)/(m - M)** and by putting
the **x** to the line **A** we find **y = ((m*(B - b))/(m - M)) + b**

so : **T : ((B - b)/(m - M) , ((m*(B - b))/(m - M)) + b)**

Comment: That may work for most cases.  However there is one important edge case where the slope of a line is undefined.  In that case your approach is not be sufficient.

Comment: @andand: you can always find the slope! Let **A: ax + by + c = 0** (it's general form) then **m** (the slope) is : **-(b/a)**

Comment: It means that the line is parallel to x axis. And at this point you have to put the y of the 2nd line to -c/b

Comment: Okay, you're changing your definition of slope then.  In your first comment above you defined slope as m=-(b/a), which if you wanted to make x dependent upon y would be okay; it's not a standard representation, but it's not improper either.  But if you do so, setting a to 0 makes the slope in this sense undefined.  In the second comment, you changed your definition of a line as a function in which y depends on x, so if we use that, the slope would be m=-(a/b) .  Here if b=0, then the line is parallel to the Y axis and its slope in that sense is undefined in that convention.

Comment: Another way to look at this, let line 1 be given (in general form) by 0*x+y+0=0 and line 2 given by x+0*y+0=0 and then apply those lines to your method above.  The correct answer is that the lines intersect at the origin, but your algorithm (regardless of the convention you use for defining the slope) will not be able to arrive at a solution.

Comment: Yes it is; it's y=0.  The other one is x=0.  Those are both lines, but the latter cannot be represented in slope-intercept form.  They can both be expressed in the general form, however.